# mssql_query() function returns false

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I wanted to read file as string with Microsoft SQL Server 2012. It does great when I run code from SQL Managment Studio, but fails from PHP function :(

```
$conn = mssql_connect($server, $user, $password);
    $query_1 = "DECLARE @FileContents VARCHAR(MAX);";
    var_dump($stmt_1 = mssql_query($query_1, $conn));
    $query_2 = "SELECT @FileContents = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:/files/some.dat',SINGLE_CLOB) BinaryFile;";
var_dump($stmt_2 = mssql_query($query_2, $conn));
```

First query is OK and returns true.
Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the contents of `mssql_get_last_message()` after the query fails. That'll tell you what's happened.

Comment: (1) why are you separating these into two queries? The second should fail because it won't have the variable declared in the first. (2) Do you expect `D:/files/` to work? I think Windows Explorer is a lot more forgiving than other applications.

Comment: @MikeW It says: Must declare the scalar variable "@FileContents".

Comment: @AaaronBertrand I've tried, but it query returned false. I added mssql_get_last_message() and now it says: 'You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.'

Comment: Well, I think you have your answer...

Comment: @AaronBertrand but query is OK when I run from SQL Managment Studio.

Comment: P.S Web and SQL Server are on different servers.

Comment: And are you connecting with the same username/password? Are you sure? I find it hard to believe that Management Studio would let you run a command that PHP wouldn't. Ultimately it's SQL Server that checks permissions and denies requests, regardless of the application.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, sure

Comment: *shrug* I don't know what else to tell you. SQL Server isn't going to say "permission denied" for fun... I would verify from SQL Server's side what username is connecting (you can check sys.dm_exec_sessions).

Comment: I'll go mad :D It works now! how? I don't know :D

Comment: I was given permissions several hours ago. Can this be a reason?